# Making at least one of two form fields mandatory in Ninja Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, ninja-forms

Using the ninja forms plugin in WordPress, I currently have Name, Email, Phone as the form fields. I would like it so the Name is required, and either email OR phone be filled out for the form to submit without an error. Is this possible?

I don't see anything on their docs that mention this anywhere, I am also considering using jQuery for this if its not possible via the plugin options.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were no replies on this I decided to use jQuery. Took me a while to figure out you need to run your function on nfFormReady.

It checks to see if field 1 OR field 2 has a value, if so then it enables the submit button, if not the submit button is disabled. It's not the most elegant solution but is working for what I need. Also beyond the below code, I added in an asterisk's and remove it on the other conditionally required field when one is being filled out.

```
$(document).on( 'nfFormReady', function() { // this is important

    // settings: for 2 dynamic-required fields
    var formID = '2'; // form ID
    var fieldID1 = '9'; // field ID one
    var fieldID2 = '12'; // field ID two
    var submitID = '11'; // Submit button ID

    $('#nf-form-' + formID + '-cont #nf-field-' + submitID + '-wrap input').attr('disabled', true).css({"background": "#cccccc", "cursor": "default"}); // disable submit button

    // on keypress/change enable submit button
    $('#nf-form-' + formID + '-cont input').on('keyup keypress focusout change', function() {
        if(($('#nf-form-' + formID + '-cont #nf-field-' + fieldID1 + '-wrap input').val()) || ($('#nf-form-' + formID + '-cont #nf-field-' + fieldID2 + '-wrap input').val())){
          $('#nf-form-' + formID + '-cont #nf-field-' + submitID + '-wrap input').attr('disabled', false).css({"background": "", "cursor": "pointer"}); // enable submit button
        }else{
          $('#nf-form-' + formID + '-cont #nf-field-' + submitID + '-wrap input').attr('disabled', true).css({"background": "#cccccc", "cursor": "default"}); // disable submit button
        };
    });
});
```